# Como Poder cambiar o dejar de usar el Framework (Vue) y solo Utilizar Arrays en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como podria cambiar o mejor dicho dejar de usar el Framwork (Vue) y que solo pueda usar arrays en javascriptm para que mi tabla generada no se vea afectada al dejar de usar ese framework, Agradeceria mucho su ayudam este codigo no es mio, lo descarguem pero quiero aplicarlo a una tarea de la escuela donde solo utilice arrays creadas en Javascript, (creo que mi problema es el no saber llamar la array de JS desde html). Por favor

[, Anexo Codepen para que miren el contenido,](https://codepen.io/YisusXpec/pen/eYYQaMq)

Comment: Será mejor que busques un código en Vanilla javascript, si quieres refactorizar este para no usar Vue no sólo tendrás que cambiar el codigo de Javascript sino también tendrás que cambiar el de HTML, saludos.

Comment: OK Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Llegaste a solucionar este problema? Si ya no necesitas ayuda o conseguiste solucionarlo agradeceríamos que compartieras la solución (yo mismo te daría un voto) o bien que cerraras la pregunta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola que tal este es un ejemplo de listado de una tabla  empleados en mysql.

```
const controller = {};

controller.list = (req, res) => {
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query("select * from customers" , (err, customers) => {

        if (err) {
            res.json(err); // convierte la respuesta a un archivo json
        }
        res.render('usuarios', {
            data: customers  // gurda los resultados en un array => data
        });
    });
});
};
```

// aqui una imagen de la vista

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>n°</th>

                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Cargo</th>
                    <th>Direccion</th>
                    <th>Telefono</th>
                    <th>Acction</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <% if (data) { %> 
                <% for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {%>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= (i + 1)%>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <%=data[i].codEmple %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%=data[i].name %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%=data[i].cargo %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%=data[i].direccion %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%=data[i].phone %>
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <a href="/delete/<%= data[i].codEmple%>" class="btn btn- 
      danger my-2">Delete</a>

                        <a href="/update/<%= data[i].codEmple%>" class="btn btn-info 
       my-2">Update</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% } %>
                <% } %>
            </tbody>

        </table>
```

Comment: En Sql si se como funciona,pero aqui me da problemas porque tambien tengo que añadir imagenes y jalarlas

Comment: sorry no entiendo si ya saves deverias poder pues es  solo recoorrer el array: ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

este es un ejemplo con vue donde se consume un archivo json o en todo caso prodria ser una api publica aunque es basico espero que te ayude... Nota:
tambien use axios.js

```
       <tr  v-for="item in lists">            
          <td><span>{{item.gender}}</span> </td>
           <td>  {{item.name.first}} {{item.name.last}} </td>
           <td> {{item.dob.age}} años</td>
           <td>  {{item.location.city}}</td>              
          <td><img style="border-radius:50%;" v-bind:src='item.picture.medium'alt="">
           </td>
       </tr>
```

aqui te dejo una muestra de json:

```
{"results":[{"gender":"male","name":{"title":"mr","first":"santana","last":"de souza"},"location":{"street":"889 travessa dos martírios","city":"abaetetuba","state":"pernambuco","postcode":22575,"coordinates":{"latitude":"-72.5312","longitude":"-138.4645"},"timezone":{"offset":"+11:00","description":"Magadan, Solomon Islands, New Caledonia"}},"email":"santana.desouza@example.com","login":{"uuid":"d5f1f092-45de-4f8e-9f8f-075334046f80","username":"lazyzebra123","password":"winston1","salt":"swY40G3t","md5":"2195d1cec2cfc37601f9a9f0bf371b6f","sha1":"26db792edb5870bcd86afed399065ae9cc42350c","sha256":"49ef6ce90f64bc3da5db2965d7f353e5e6c66374a524de817074db4d328d086c"},"dob":{"date":"1970-01-10T10:34:04Z","age":48},"registered":{"date":"2008-02-19T18:10:26Z","age":10},"phone":"(22) 0339-5008","cell":"(92) 4716-5767","id":{"name":"","value":null},"picture":{"large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/24.jpg","medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/24.jpg","thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/24.jpg"},"nat":"BR"}
```

este es js:

```
  var mylist = 'userlong.json';

           const myVue = new Vue({
              el:'#main',
              created: function(){
                  this.getUsers();  
              },
              data: {
                  lists:[]

              },
              methods: {
                  getUsers:function(){
                      axios.get(mylist).then(response =>{
                          this.lists = response.data.results;
                      });
                  }
              }

          });
```

Comment: De hecho si te evisas de nuevo, lo que el OP trata es dejar de usar Vue